# How can I fix the result which it does not respond?

Tags: python

I've been coding for my course.
It wants input but it doesn't show the result.
Here my code:

```
def XYZ():
    n = int(input("Enter A Number:"))
    z = list(range(1, n + 1))

    def fact(n):
        while True:
            if n == 1:
                return 1
            return n * fact(n - 1)

    def Summation(List):
        if len(List) == 1:
            return List[0]
        else:
            return List[0] + Summation(List[1:])

    z1 = [i / fact(i) for i in z]
    return Summation(z1)

XYZ()
```

Comment: There's nothing in this code that should "show" anything. Have you tried ``print(XYZ())``?

Comment: We need more details on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Works for me, and gives `2.7182815255731922`, i.e. the value of `e`. Maybe you should just add `print`, like `print (XYZ())` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several [IDE](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/ide)s available for python, which is based on user choice and preferences. For instance, much *data scientist* or related persons use the so-called *Jupyter Notebook* which comes with the [*anaconda*](https://www.anaconda.com/) distribution.

Now, Jupyter Notebook will show the output *in-line* of the last statement/code executed (if there is something to print) without actually providing a `print(var)` statement. But, this is not the case for many other IDEs or if you run the code from terminal/command prompt - there you must add `print(XYZ())`, as commented previously. Hope this answered your question!

Coming to *coding prespective*, I don't see any point of making your code so complicated just to do a *"simple factorial"* of a number. This can be achieved by just using a single line of code:

```py
import math

def factorial(n):
    return math.prod(list(range(n, 0, -1)))

print(factorial(n = int(input("Enter a Number:"))))
```

There are several reasons for this:

1. It is better to keep your input/arguments outside your function. This gives you more control.
2. Using inbuilt basic tools like `math` or `os` etc. makes your code much faster.
3. If you still want to go for functions without using a single library, you can include your summation within a single function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
def XYZ():
    n = int(input("Enter A Number: "))
    z = list(range(1, n + 1))

    def fact(n):
        while True:
            if n == 1:
                return 1
            return n * fact(n - 1)

    def Summation(List):
        if len(List) == 1:
            return List[0]
        else:
            return List[0] + Summation(List[1:])

    z1 = [i / fact(i) for i in z]
    return Summation(z1)

result = XYZ()
print(result)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.